# How do I create a header that has a colored box with page number, Chaptername, and also a line across the textwidth after it?

Tags: header-footer, color, rules

I would like to create a fancy header that looks like this. I am writing a two-sided book with a5paper. 
[image: Header with line after chapter name]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this for the page header or the chapter heading?

Comment: My apologies for the unclear question. It is for the page header of the book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### scrlayer-scrpage

Here is a suggestion using [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage).

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\setlength\headheight{13.1pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{headbgcolor}{green!50!blue!70}

\usepackage[markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\enskip}

\lehead*{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{
    \colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\pagemark\enskip}}\hspace*{1em}}%
  \headmark\hspace*{1em}\headrulefill%
}
\rohead*{%
  \headrulefill\hspace*{1em}\headmark%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \hspace*{1em}\colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\enskip\pagemark}}}%
}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries\color{white}}
\newcommand\headrulefill{\leaders\hrule width 0pt height 3pt depth -2.8pt \hfill}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the chapter page should not get the header remove the stars after `\lehead` and `\rohead`.

### fancyhdr

And here is an example using [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\setlength\headheight{13.1pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{headbgcolor}{green!50!blue!70}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\enskip#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[LE]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{
    \colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thepage}\enskip}}\hspace*{1em}}%
  {\itshape\leftmark}\hspace*{1em}\headrulefill%
}
\fancyhead[RO]{%
  \mbox{}\headrulefill \hspace*{1em}{\itshape\leftmark}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \hspace*{1em}\colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\enskip\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thepage}}}}%
}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

\def\headrulefill{\leaders\hrule width 0pt height 3pt depth -2.8pt \hfill}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If the chapter page should get the same header you have to redefine the fancypagestyle `plain`, too.

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE]{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{
      \colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thepage}\enskip}}\hspace*{1em}}%
    {\itshape\leftmark}\hspace*{1em}\headrulefill%
  }
  \fancyhead[RO]{%
    \mbox{}\headrulefill \hspace*{1em}{\itshape\leftmark}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \hspace*{1em}\colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\enskip\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thepage}}}}%
  }
}
```

Comment: Two superb solutions! I have tried both and they gave the outputs that I needed. Since I am more familiar with fancyhdr, I will use your second option. Only one slight issue: for the fancyhdr solution, the page number's font is not consistent - even page has normal font and odd page has italized font. That could be easily fixed right?

Comment: Alhough I am told to avoid saying thanks, I would still like to say thanks to @esdd for posting a solution for me. This solution has opened up some huge possibilities for designing colorful and eye-capturing page headers instead of boring ones that I have seen latex do. I think more examples like these really help end-users like me work in the latex-ing world.

Comment: @pyro I have changed the `fancyhdr` example: now the page numbers should have normal font on both even and odd pages.

Comment: Fabulous! Now they are perfect! TQVM!